# In Rails, how to get the actual Query when an ActiveRecord query executes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am using a simple query in ActiveRecord which does something like this.

```
MyTable.find(:all, :conditions => {:start_date => format_time(params[:date]) })
```

I want to get the equivalent query that is executed in the background, perhaps using a `puts` statement or something similar to that. MySQL is my database.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can see the SQL query that is executed by viewing the development log located in `log/development.log`. Note that the `script/server` command tails this log file by default.

- In Rails 3 you can append a `.to_sql` method call to the end of the finder to output the SQL.
- Alternatively, [New Relic](http://www.newrelic.com/)'s free RPM Lite gem lets you see the SQL queries in developer mode as well as lots of other useful performance tuning information.

Comment: But its so crowded in the log file. Is there anyway to separate it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can insatll **mongrel**

its gets you all sql queries on your terminal

or run active record query on **script/console**

Answer (score 0):

In development mode, your DB queries are printed to the server console, you can localize the query there.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `construct_finder_sql`.

```
>> User.send(:construct_finder_sql, {:conditions => { :username => 'joe' }})
=> "SELECT * FROM \"users\" WHERE (\"users\".\"username\" = E'joe') "

>> User.scoped(:joins => :orders, :conditions => { :username => 'joe' }).send(:construct_finder_sql, {})
=> "SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\"   INNER JOIN \"orders\" ON orders.user_id = users.id  WHERE (\"users\".\"username\" = E'joe') "
```